# Spartacus, refresh orders after cancellation fail

Tags: reload, orders, ngrx-store, spartacus-storefront

I made a custom service to cancel an order, after trigger it, when I get the server response 'OK' I reload the order's list but the order status isn't refreshed. It takes several seconds to do so.
Is there any service or flag that I could use to refresh the list when the data store state has changed?
I tried several services without success...

```
 this.userOrderService.getCancelOrderSuccess().subscribe... // state still not cancelled
 this.userOrdersEffect.resetUserOrders$.subscribe // neither this
```

Answer (score 1):

I checked with my colleagues who are responsible for order status implementation in Commerce Cloud backend. Unfortunately the behavior you have observed so far is working as designed: order status is updated in Commerce Cloud backend in an asynchronous way, there is nothing can do to catch the event when the order status is really changed. Perhaps you can check whether there is a email sent when order status change is done.

Best Regards,
Jerry

Comment: Thanks, at least now I can try something else.